# Looping through two arrays having different lengths

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, while-loop

I have two arrays, length of one is longer than second one. I'm looping by comparing the numbers in first index `[1]` of every array in the parrent array. As written in if statement of code below. if the numbers are equal in both child arrays then these arrays are pushed to the new array.

But as 'secondArr' array is longer then the other one, if that number is not found in 'arr' then I it should get the child array with most closer value of `[1]` index.

Shortly `newArray` should have the same length as `secondArr` as it is longer than `arr`. When any value is not found in the `arr` `newArray` should get the child array of current index in case of `secondArr` and the child of the most closer previous array with `[1]` in `arr`. Ex: when `'250'`, '`270'`, `'280'` are found in `secondArr` they should all get `['fd', 250]` from arr as '250' in arr has `'250'` in `[1]` which is the closest value of previous index in `arr` to the numbers cerrent loop index in 'secondArr'

```
var arr = [ 
            ['asd', 100],
            ['fde', 200],
            ['fd', 250],
            ['asd',300],
            ['fa', 340]
          ]
var secondArr = [
                   ['adzx', 100],
                   ['tre', 140],
                   ['vc', 200],
                   ['brt', 250],
                   ['azc', 270],
                   ['sfds', 280],
                   ['we', 300],
                   ['jyt',550]
                ]
var i = secondArr.length;

var newArr = []    

while(i--){
      //TODO if arr[i][1] != secondArr[i][1] then arr[i-1][1]
      if(arr[i][1] == secondArr[i][1]){
            newArr.push(
                [
                arr[i],
                secondArr[i]
                ]                
            )
      }
}
```

So I want `newArray` to be equal to:

```
newArray = [ 
        [   ['asd', 100],
            ['adzx', 100]
        ],
        [
            ['asd', 100],
            ['tre', 140]
        ],
        [
            ['fde', 200],
            ['vc', 200]
        ],
        [
            ['fd', 250],
            ['brt', 250]
        ],
        [
            ['fd', 250],
            ['azc', 270]
        ],
        [
            ['fd', 250],
            ['sfds', 280]
        ],
        [
            ['asd',300],
            ['we', 300]
        ],
        [
            ['fa', 340],
            ['jyt',550]
        ],
    ]
```

In current case of `arr` and `secondArray`

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't see a question. What are looking for?

Comment: please add some example solution array.

Comment: Is it clear right now? did you understand what an array should look like?

Comment: @developer, thank you for the added array. it makes clear, what you want.

Comment: Nina -Thank you for your solution :). That upvote was from me :) I didn't really test your result in my project, but it seems to be correct. Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this solution works for you.

It is utilizing a correction mechanism for the left (`arr`) value comparison.

```js
var arr = [['asd', 100], ['fde', 200], ['fd', 250], ['asd', 300], ['fa', 340]],
    secondArr = [['adzx', 100], ['tre', 140], ['vc', 200], ['brt', 250], ['azc', 270], ['sfds', 280], ['we', 300], ['jyt', 550]],
    i = 0,
    result = secondArr.map(function (a) {
        while (i + 1 < arr.length && arr[i + 1][1] <= a[1]) {
            i++;
        }
        return [arr[i], a];
    });
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score -1):

In your while loop you start with i = secondArr.length which is greater than arr.length. Therefore your arr[i][1] will throw a TypeError.